# vb.net stream reader reads from a .accdb and .xml file without an error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to full-proof my tool, and I noticed that if you pass a database file to streamreader, it will read the file without a problem,. I would like to only be able to open text files (.txt, .xml, .json, etc.). I want the tool to exit if it tries to read an excel document or something not written in plain text.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you're having a specific problem.

Comment: This was already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4744890/1732224 - it's C#, but shouldn't be a problem to change the code to VB.NET.

Comment: Check the file extension and make sure it's correct. That doesn't stop someone from changing the file extension though. You could check the characters like suggested in the linked thread, but what if they are all integers?  Any solution here is going to be fuzzy. You may spend a lot of time putting in checks for cases that will never happen. Funny thing about Excel files, they're written in XML, which is a file "type" that you want to accept. See the problem?

Comment: It looks like they answered my questions, unless vb has a magical alternative that doesn't translate to C#.