define git merge strategy for certain file extension, or prevent it at all
today I observed a git behaviour at work:
we use a git repository to store proprietary binary files. (don't ask why, its the only way to exchange versioned files for us in a sane way).
And it seems that git when merging / restoring stashes destroys that files.
Is there a way to prevent git from writing to those files and query for manual resolving?

Declare them binary?

Also consider using a custom merge driver.

@phd how? more information?

@eftshift0 whats that? Never heared of

@schnedan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030698/do-i-really-need-to-specify-all-binary-files-in-gitattributes Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+declare+file+binary

@schnedan https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+custom+merge+driver
